# Simplicial model categories and simplicial equivalence

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $M$ and $N$ two very nice simplicial model categories and let $F:N\rightarrow M$ be a (nice) simplicial functor which induces an equivalence of homotopy categories, i.e. $Ho(F): Ho(N)\rightarrow Ho(M)$  is an equivalence of homotopy categories and it is well defined. We define the category $\pi_{0}M$ as the category having the same objects  of $M$ and $Hom_{\pi_{0}M}(a,b)=\pi_{0}Map_{M}(a,b)$.

What can we say about the functor $\pi_{0}F:\pi_{0}N\rightarrow \pi_{0}M$? is it an equivalence of categories. Maybe we should assume that $F$ takes cofibrant-fibrant objects to cofibrant-fibrant objects... or something close to that.

Clarification: A simplicial functor between simplicial model categories $M$ and $N$ is a simplicial enriched functor between simplicial enriched categories.

Clarification II:  A simplicial model category is a model category $M$ tensored and cotensored over the  model category of simplicial sets in a way compatible with model structure of both model structure on $M$ and on simplicial sets.

**Edit** I think there is a counterexample: Let $M=N$ be the standard model category of simplicial sets, and let $F: sSet\rightarrow sSet$ be the functor of fibrant replacement such that it is simpllicial (I guess such functor do exist). Then $\pi_{0}F$ is not an equivalence of categories, while $Ho(F)$ is. I'm I right ?

Comment: How are you defining $\mathrm{Map}$? In general you'll need to take some kind of (co)fibrant replacement of the arguments to get the correct homotopy type of the mapping space...

Comment: @DenisNardin M is a simplicial model category, $Map$ is given enrichment by definition. Do I misunderstand your question ?

Comment: I think the clarification for $Map$ comes from different authors using it for different things, for example, simplicial enrichment, homotopy function complexes, etc etc

Comment: It would be helpful if some context was provided as to the origin of this question.  Why would we want to consider π_0(M) in the first place?  This is a fairly atypical thing to do to a simplicial model category.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I'm learning model categories, I found out that I should start with simplicial model categories since I have some problems to digest the technical definitions of a general model category. My question is maybe naive for the experts. I wanted just to see what is the difference between $\pi_{0}M$ and $Ho(M)$ and how much information is missed passing from $\pi_{0}M$ to the full subcategory  $Ho(M)$. I have edited my question with a potential counterexample.

Comment: @Amadeus: π_0(sSet) contains Ho(sSet) as a full subcategory, but is much bigger than Ho(sSet), essentially because nonfibrant simplicial sets are poorly behaved with respect to simplicial homotopies.  For instance, the inclusion of Δ^0 into Δ^n as an interior vertex i (0<i<n) is not a simplicial homotopy equivalence.  Kan's Ex^∞ functor is a simplicial fibrant replacement functor for simplicial sets.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: I am not sure what definition of simplicial homotopy equivalence you are using, but for the sake of computing $\pi_0$, which relies on taking a closure by transitivity of the notion of homotopy equivalence, the inclusion of $\Delta^0$ into $\Delta^n$ is an homotopy equivalence. You can always write it as a composition of "elementary" homotopy equivalence by writing $\Delta^0\to \Delta^1\to \dots\to \Delta^n$.

Comment: @S.Douteau: I am using the standard definition of simplicial homotopy equivalence: a map f:X→Y such that there is g:Y→X and h_X:Δ^1×X→X and h_Y:Δ^1×Y→Y that are homotopies between id_X and gf respectively fg and id_Y.  This yields the correct notion for Kan complexes.  "Closure by transitivity" of homotopy equivalences for non-Kan complexes does not give the correct notion: there are many pairs of maps f,g:X→Y that become identical maps in Ho(sSet), but are not homotopic in your sense (e.g., one could enhance my example by taking infinite disjoint unions of simplices of increasing dimension).

Comment: @DmitriPavlov You are right, I should not use the term homotopy equivalences for these maps. However, what I meant by "closure by transitivity" is that when one wants to compute actual sets of homotopy classes of maps between two spaces, one needs to quotient out the set of maps by the homotopy relation. And to do so, a closure by transitivity is needed unless both spaces are bifibrant. Furthermore, this set of homotopy classes is exactly $\pi_0Map_M(a,b)$, and even though it does not correspond to the Homset in the homotopy category, there is still a well defined map $[X,Y]\to Hom_{Ho}(X,Y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is an answer to the question, I think I should write it down.

There is a simple counterexample to my question: Let $M=N=sSet$ the standard model category of simplicial sets. Let $ex^{\infty}:sSet\rightarrow sSet$ the fibrant replacement functor. It is simplicial as it was noticed in the comments. $Ho(F)$ is well defined and induce an (auto)equivalence of the homotopy category $Ho(sSet)$. On the other hand $\pi_{0}(F)$ is clearly not an autoequivalence of $\pi_{0}sSet$.